# How to provide pre-aggregated subtotals in a pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Is there some way to provide your own values for the grouping rows in a pivot table. I have data from an external system with values provided for all drilldown levels, laid out as rows. There is one column per aggregation level and the sublevels are blank for rows which provide aggregate values.

An trivial example is a 2 level drilldown per region and country where we ahve the columns

```
Region; Country; Value
```

We might have the two rows

```
Europe; Germany; 10
Europe; France; 12
```

and the aggregate row

`Europe; (blank); 25` (the value is not additive, so not simply the sum of the two previous rows)

The problem is now that if I try to createa drilldown report in excel, the pivot table functionality simply interprets the blank entry as another entry on the most  granular level and then sums over the rows to provide a total for Europe. The resulting total will be 10 + 12 + 25 instead of just 25.

Is there some way of presenting such "pre-aggregated" data in a drilldown report in excel?

Thanks,
Rickard

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude blanks from the result by using the drop down menu on `Row Labels` but there is a trick. The contents of the drop down are dependent on what cell is currently active in the pivot table. Make sure that one of the Country names is selected, or '(blank)', and then open the drop down menu. You can deselect (blank) and it will be removed from the aggregates.

Comment: Thank you. This solves the first half of the problem. The next step would be to be able to _use_ the blanks as aggregates, rather than letting the pivot table calculate the aggregates. This I suspect is not trivial or even possible...